# Sprint boot async - does not use max-size

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous

I am trying out Spring Boot's Async feature, but I am having some trouble getting it to work as I need.
This is my application yml

```
spring:
  task:
    execution:
      pool:
        max-size: 100
        queue-capacity: 5
        keep-alive: "10s"
        core-size: 10
```

Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class ServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Service class:

```
for (int i=0;i< 40; i++) {
      CompletableFuture.runAsync(()-> {
        try {
          System.out.println("------------------Starting thread------------------");
          //do some action here
          System.out.println("------------------Ending thread------------------");
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      });
    }
```

I am expecting to see the System.out print out 40 times. The operations in between take long enough, and I have tried adding Thread.sleep(), but I do not see the sysouts printed more than 8 times. Is there something wrong with my config, or does it not work the way I expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completable future has no idea about the pool that is used by Spring.

From docs of `runAsync()` method:

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a
> task running in the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() after it runs the given
> action. Params: runnable – the action to run before completing the
> returned CompletableFuture Returns: the new CompletableFuture

So, those tasks are being run on `ForkJoinPool`, not on executor used by Spring.

[About executor used by Spring with @EnableAsync](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html):

> By default, Spring will be searching for an associated thread pool
> definition: either a unique TaskExecutor bean in the context, or an
> Executor bean named "taskExecutor" otherwise. If neither of the two is
> resolvable, a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor will be used to process async
> method invocations. Besides, annotated methods having a void return
> type cannot transmit any exception back to the caller. By default,
> such uncaught exceptions are only logged.

You could try autowire that executor and pass it as an argument to

```java
public static CompletableFuture<Void> runAsync(Runnable runnable, Executor executor)
```

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a
> task running in the given executor after it runs the given action.
> Params: runnable – the action to run before completing the returned
> CompletableFuture executor – the executor to use for asynchronous
> execution